# Pass Parameter to Laravel toArray() Eloquent Model

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I've a method in my `Controller`:

```
function getSuggestions()
{
   $query = Input::get('query');
   $suggestions = Suggestion::where('word', 'LIKE', "$query%")->get()->toArray();
   $return $suggestions; 
}
```

and in `Model` I have:

```
 public function toArray(){
        $array = parent::toArray();
        $array['matched'] = 'ok';
        return $array;
    }
```

How can I pass a variable to this `toArray()` method to append it to the `Model`? 
Something like this: `$array['matched'] = $query`
I can't pass the `$query` directly to `toArray($query)`. Any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the value to each matched array:

```
function getSuggestions()
{
    $query = Input::get('query');
    $suggestions = Suggestion::where('word', 'LIKE', "$query%")->get()->toArray();
    return array_map(
        function ($array) use ($query) { $array['matched'] = $query; return $array; },
        $suggestions
    );
}
```